# FB.ui() giving error in Safari with asynchronous request when user is not already logged in 

Tags: asynchronous, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get have users be able to post to their Facebook walls on my external site.

I've encountered a problem in Safari. If the user isn't logged in, i.e. they have not gone through the flow that calls FB.login(), I get the following JS error when calling FB.ui():

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.fbCallID=a.id')

However, if they are logged in, the dialog appears just fine.

FB.ui() is called in a callback function -- I'm retrieving a unique url from my server, and then calling FB.ui(). If I call FB.ui() directly, it works fine, but not when it's asynchronous.

Here's the code:

```
        retrieveUrl(param1, param2, function(result) {
            FB.ui({ method:  'feed',
                    description: 'My Description',
                    display: 'dialog',
                    link:    result.uniqueUrl,
                    picture: 'http://foo.com/bar.jpg'
            }, function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    //Posted message
                } else {
                    //Not posted message
                }
            });
        });
```

This works in other browsers, regardless of logged in state or not.

Answer (score 4):

FB.login or FB.ui methods must be called on a user initiated action (click) in Safari for new window/popup/iframe to be rendered by FB.UIServer.

If you try calling these methods on a network callback event it will be blocked and the exception you described will occur:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.fbCallID=a.id')

Can you retrieve the unique URL before the user interacts with the page and then present the feed dialog when they click on a button?

Comment: No, definitely can't. I need my server to generate a unique code first. I just did the redirect instead of using FB.ui(), so it's ok.

Comment: maybe the unique code can be generate with the page? Meh. Redirect away!